# how to build a method to get the component on the inherited form from the base form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, interface

I Have a base form with the following code:

```
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.InitRibbonPageGroups()
End Sub

Sub InitRibbonPageGroups()

    Dim Ribbon As RibbonControl = Nothing

    For Each c As Object In Me.Controls
        If Not TryCast(c, WCLib.ClsCompMyRibbonControl) Is Nothing Then
            Ribbon = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Ribbon Is Nothing Then
        For Each P As RibbonPage In Ribbon.Pages
            For Each RPG As WCLib.ClsCompMyRibbonPageGroup In P.Groups
                RPG.Visible = RPG.InitialVisibility
            Next
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

My problem is that on the base form the component "RibbonControl" does not exist it will exists only on the Form who Inherits from the base. So when this method runs he dont find any control on the me.controls.

My question is if are there any way to achieve this task, I couldn't find an identifier to replace  the "Me." one to get the control from the base.

Answer (score 0):

Any `RibbonControl` on a derived form is visible from the base form. Your problem is not the visibility but the program flow.

The base class' constructor is executed before the constructors of derived classes. Thus, when `InitRibbonPageGroups` is called, the concrete class' constructor has not added its controls to the `Controls` collection yet. That's why the base class can't find it.

The solution is simple: Execute `InitRibbonPageGroups` only when the `RibbonControl` has been added, e.g. at the end of the derived class' constructor:

```
Public Class DerivedForm Inherits BaseForm
    Public Sub New
        InitializeComponent()
        InitRibbonPageGroups()
    End Sub
    '...
```

Btw, you should make `InitRibbonPageGroups` `Protected` if you do not need to call it from outside.